# Capture/group specific symbol under certain conditions with regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, bbcode

Here is my situation:

> Text [b Text Here  ] <--capture the 1st "]", not -->[b]

Using `(\[b)(?:\s.*)(?:\s|)(\])` it skips `]`   captures the `-->[b]`

How would I capture the *first* `[` or `]` *after* the `[b     Text...` with any character/whitespace/digit before it?

Better seen/understood [here](http://regexr.com/38vg5)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a lazy repeat:

```
.*?
```

So your regex would look like

```
(\[b)(?:\s.*?)(?:\s|)(\])
```

Otherwise, regular expression are greedy, and would consume as many tokens as they can.

You can read more about laziness and greediness here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: With slight modification that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need a positive lookbehind :

```
(?<=b Text Here ).
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/mL2hD6